# how to synchronize transactions?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

Imagine that I have a page shows like below

Balance  $100                                 shopping cart

Total price $90                    Book 2: $10

                                            Book 1: $80

--------------------
Final price $10

How can I ensure synchronization here? 
For example, if two persons use the same account and send different transactions at the same time. That will lead to some horrible things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what locking is for.

Lock the variable that stores `Balance` and then update the value and then unlock it. Then when the second transaction will try to lock and update, it will fail for insufficient balance.

Comment: May you explain how to lock Balance? Such as if there are two users use same account then how to lock the Balance parameter in the front-end page?

Comment: @apss1943: What database/programming language are you using?

Comment: @apss1943: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for java. This will get you to control concurrency on the front-end. I'm hoping that your data is not distributed over multiple servers.

Comment: I think this one is more relative to what I really want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589792.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As @displayName suggested this is a classic usage of locks.

Adding one point:
For single server the options are :
1.  thread shared local variable .
2. singleton class which gives the resource for the repository and locks the resource/repository.

For distributed servers with sql, you can use sql locks.

Comment: Both of the ideas are not too bad at all, yet I am considering that if there are over thousands of people using it at the same time.